# Convert a string into routeValues for call RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routevalues

Is possible to convert a string into routeValues?

Per example:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = 1});
```

**to**

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", "id = 1");
```

I am needing it because I want to save the routeValues in database.

I already read this: [convert string into (object) routeValues C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434198/convert-string-into-object-routevalues-c-sharp) but the guy doesn't know if that is the more supported way.

Comment: can you not save the full url in the database? `var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 1});`  then you just use `return Redirect(url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` also takes a `RouteValueDictionary` which might be usable in your case.  You'd have to construct it a little differently.

```
var routeVals = new RouteValueDictionary(){"id", "1"};
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", routeVals);
```